# Is accessing int as unsigned long undefined behavior?

Tags: c, winapi, type-punning

In a book called Programming Windows, in one of the examples, we have [this](https://github.com/yottaawesome/programming-windows-5th-edition/blob/master/src/Chap09/head/head.c#L179) line:

```
ReadFile (hFile, buffer, MAXREAD, &i, NULL) ;
```

`i` here was [previously](https://github.com/yottaawesome/programming-windows-5th-edition/blob/master/src/Chap09/head/head.c#L73) declared as `int`, but the 4th argument of [`ReadFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-readfile) is `LPDWORD`, which is a typedef for `DWORD*`, and `DWORD` is a typedef for `unsigned long`. It's effectively type punning. On most systems `unsigned long` and `int` are the same size, but I think accessing a variable as if it were some other type is Undefined Behavior. Is this fine? Is this fine only if the sizes are the same? Is this UB? I checked a couple of errata websites and they don't seem to list this. Am I missing something?

Comment: *On most systems `unsigned long` and `int` are the same size*  No, they're not.  Windows is the outlier here.   On just about every other 64-bit architecture, an `int` is 32 bits while an `[unsigned] long` is 64 bites.

Comment: This is an error in the book. `i` should be declared as a `DWORD`.

Comment: If you read up to 2GB (bit 31 is zero), there is no problem.

Comment: Note that VC++ will warn about this these days. It's not best practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `DWORD` is defined as you describe, then the code contains a constraint violation which the compiler must diagnose , and the Standard no longer covers the behaviour of any executable generated.  [There is no implicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828742/technical-legality-of-incompatible-pointer-assignments) from `int *` to `unsigned long *`, regardless of the sizes of types.

If you don't see a compiler error message I would strongly recommend adjusting compiler settings so that an error message is shown. Some compilers default to showing a "warning" message for this mistake which can mislead the unwary into thinking there is no real problem.

Comment: In C++, there is no implicit conversion between pointer types, but I think in C there is. Could you cite the relevant parts of the standard saying this is undefined? Some people claim it's fine if they are the same size, others claim it's fine if you don't read more than `int` could hold.

Comment: @Ayxan I added link to another l-l question on that subject, the person quotes the standard  in the question

Comment: @Ayxan The program is invalid (either in C or C++) so there is nothing to define here.

Comment: *"the compiler must diagnose"* - Could you provide a reference? I believe this is a case of the dreaded IFNDR (ill-formed, no diagnostic required).

Comment: @IInspectable C doesn't have "ill-formed", you're thinking of another language. There is a link in my answer to the relevant standard quotes that it is a constraint violation, also see C11 5.1.1.3 specifying that a constraint violation must produce a diagnostic