# int (*d)(int *) = foo, what does this part of the code do?

Tags: c, initialization, function-pointers, declaration, implicit-conversion

```
int foo (int x) {
    int (*d)(int *) = foo;  //what is the meaning of this line?
    ...
}
```

this is an old practice question from my school, but i couldn't find the solution for it.
Is it initializing a variable to a function?

Comment: d is a pointer to a function which takes an int * argument and returns int.  It is being assigned the address of foo. This should give a warning.

Comment: It's the somewhat confusing syntax for representing the type of a function pointer. The most confusing part is that the name of the variable  (`d`) does not follow the type, but is embedded in it.

Comment: If it is a question from your school, either you or they missed something in the curriculum.

Comment: [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*d%29%28int+*%29) is great for that.

Comment: Consider the function pointer type of `foo` to be `int (*)(int)`. `int (*d)(int)` just gives it the name `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This record

```
int (*d)(int *) = foo;
```

is a declaration of the function pointer `d` to function that has the return type `int` and one parameter of the type `int *`. This pointer is initialized by the address of the function `foo` (the function designator is implicitly converted to pointer to it).

Pay attention to that either the function `foo` should be declared like

```
int foo (int *x) {
```

or the pointer should be declared like

```
int (*d)(int ) = foo;
```

Otherwise in this declaration

```
int (*d)(int *) = foo;
```

there are used incompatible pointer types.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell the `a` declaration is irrelevant to your question. `int (*d)(int *)` defines a pointer `d` to a function that takes an `int *` and returns an `int`. `= foo` sets `d` equal to the address of `foo`.

Comment: (Which has undefined behaviour because the prototypes don't match.)

Comment: [@Neil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70636679/int-dint-foo-what-does-this-part-of-the-code-do#comment124869268_70636718) "has undefined behaviour because the prototypes don't match" --> C spec has "A pointer to a function of one type may be converted to a pointer to a function of another type and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer. If a converted pointer is used to call a function whose type is not compatible with the referenced type, the behavior is undefined.".  As I see it the assignment is **not** UB.  Calling `d()` is UB.

Comment: @user17732522 Are you suggesting that a properly casted initialization is OK, but OP's is UB?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that is a very good distinction.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Practically no, technically as far as the standard is concerned, I guess so (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36828742/technical-legality-of-incompatible-pointer-assignments.) With `-pedantic-errors` the compilers do not compile the code, but I'll remove my comment. I shouldn't be language-lawyering in such a question.